# How can I sync SharePoint 2013 Online with my on-premise SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, office-365, migration, sync

I have an on-premise SharePoint 2010.  I want to gradually start migrating my lists and document libraries up to SharePoint 2013 Online (Office 365).  Once the data is in SharePoint 2013 Online, it will be pretty much read-only for now with most of the work still being done in 2010.

I've found some ways to get the data into 2013 (exporting as Excel or Document Library Templates) but I'm wanting something that is scheduled and routinely pushes the data from the on-premise 2010 up to SharePoint Online.

Any way to do that OOTB?  Alternative solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being in this scenario now, I would offer this advice.

Invest in a third party migration tool. This has been immensely invaluable in that we can do an initial push of list or library content, then use scheduled or on demand incremental synchronizations of content depending on the need. This also helps with cutover or go-live to SPO as you can be synching content in the back ground until you are ready to go live.

For the record, we use Content Matrix from Metalogix, but there are a lot of other vendors in this space.

Comment: Metalogix handles the synchronization as well as the initial data move?  Would you recommend them?

Comment: The synchronization is done through incremental updates, it isn't a real time sync. It is a powerful flexible tool, but pricey. I would recommend it if your budget allows for it. It can tap into the Azure migration pipeline too.

Comment: Definitely use a 3rd party tool.  I'm a big fan of the ShareGate tool.  Support is top notch and it's got killer PowerShell support.  The price is waaay below MetaLogix and AvePoint, but all 3 get the job done.  Metalogix does offer free version that supports up to 25GB of data transfer.

Comment: @JesusShelby I went with ShareGate for the PowerShell support.  Works great so far.  Wish it was faster but I'm probably underestimating all the work it's doing behind the scenes.